# Regex for alphanumeric word and should not be like RUN123456

Tags: regex, pcre, alphanumeric

I want to apply regex on a string to get alphanumeric value and the value should not start with the `RUN` substring followed with any digit, e.g. `RUN123456`.

Below is the regex I am using to get alphanumeric value

```
regex='[A-Z]{2,}[_0-9a-zA-Z]*'
```

Sample Input:

```
CY0PNI94980 Production AutoSys Job has failed. Call 249-3344. EC=54.  RUN130990.
```

The matches can include `CY0PNI94980` and `EC`, but not `RUN130990`.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid matching `RUN130990`? What is peculiar about it? Do you want to match your pattern at the start of string only? `^[A-Z]{2,}[_0-9a-zA-Z]*`?

Comment: I want match pattern anywhere in string and the values except RUN******

Comment: Like [`\b(?!RUN[0-9])[A-Z]{2,}[_0-9a-zA-Z]*`](https://regex101.com/r/tecW36/1)?

Comment: It's working ... Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You may match the strings matching your pattern excluding all those starting with `RUN` and a digit:

```
\b(?!RUN[0-9])[A-Z]{2,}[_0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tecW36/1)

If you do not care if you match Unicode letters or digits or not, you may contract `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `\w` and use

```
\b(?!RUN[0-9])[A-Z]{2,}\w*
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!RUN[0-9])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `RUN` and any ASCII digit immediately to the right of the current location
- `[A-Z]{2,}` - 2 or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `[_0-9a-zA-Z]*` / `\w*` - 0 or more word chars (letters/digits/`_`).